# Typehint for a class as parameter in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, function, class, static, type-hinting

How can I typehint a parameter which is a class with a specific static function?

Cheap tricks like `any` aren't what I'm looking for - the code works but I want it to be clean, so my IDE tells me when I enter incorrect paramers (eg. a class which doesn't implement the called function).

```ts
class Example1{
    static foo():string{
        return "Example1";
    }
}
class Example2{
    static foo():string{
        return "Example2";
    }
}

class Factory{
    static create(callback /** what typehint would be correct here */):string{
        return callback.foo();
    }
}

console.log(Factory.create(Example1));
console.log(Factory.create(Example2));
```

An interactive example can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeYC2AHEBTAjAbwFDQOggBcxiBLYaAMwHtaAKASgC4SAncgOwHM9CB0dumIBXdl2gAiBMjRYpAbnyEAvrnWhIMWagwAmfoRJlKNeszbFOvI4KEjxkmYj3p9SlQXXrcWqNAAYmDAxLTsAJ52RKQUVMDCZOgMwGAgIABGIQDW0AD0AFQF0ADuABZk0MQRKOhl3MSltKIgACbQGejQwOHCodBl6MLQBXmsHNx8XoLCYhLdaZk5AHR0jEzKAj64frRcELQYyyC0PAzBoeERywnoSQy68phMG7v7h+jHp+chYZE3iWIyUeBheyiAA).

Comment: `{foo: () => string}`?

Comment: Now I feel dump - to easy. Thanks! Would you like to comment so I can mark your answer as the solution?